# Which variable declaration optimize memory performance

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Which method optimize memory or is it same ?.
Does `GameObject` of **Method 1** create a new memory allocation for every loop ?, since I believe `GameObject` of **Method 2** using the same memory reference.

> Does `Method 1` create **GC** or create new memory allocation that will reduce performance ?

**Method 1**

```
foreach (GameObject child in childs)
{
    GameObject obj = otherObj.GetComponent<Transform>().gameObject;
    //do something with obj
}

foreach(GameObject child in child2)
{
    GameObject obj = otherObj2.GetComponent<Transform>().gameObject;
    //do something with obj
}
```

**Method 2**

```
GameObject obj;
foreach (GameObject child in childs)
{
    obj = otherObj.GetComponent<Transform>().gameObject;
    //do something with obj
}

foreach(GameObject child in child2)
{
    obj = otherObj2.GetComponent<Transform>().gameObject;
    //do something with obj
}
```

Comment: There's only a difference in the scope of the reference, which is a local variable.  In MSIL that C# compiles to, locals are preallocated at the beginning of the function.  Method 2 does leave the very last object from each loop reachable outside the loop, while Method 1 does not, which could theoretically affect the GC's root-reachability analysis (the .NET Framework CLR looks at the last instruction in the function that uses a local, I don't know whether the Unity compilers do this)

Comment: also foreach can cause gc issues, see here: http://www.gamasutra.com/blogs/WendelinReich/20131109/203841/C_Memory_Management_for_Unity_Developers_part_1_of_3.php

Answer (score 1):

GC stress of both methods is the same. The culprit is not the `obj` but rather the `foreach`. If you iterate using `for`, you can do this loop without any memory allocation:

```
for(int i = 0; i < transform.childCount; i++){
        GameObject obj = transform.GetChild(i).GetComponent<Transform>().gameObject;
        //do something with obj
    }
```

Comment: base on above method,how bout the `int i` and `obj`, i thought it allocate atleast two memory location for each. I really need deeper understand of how memory is used when certain variable is created, since it will help me code better.

Comment: Try reading Gamasutra article @mgear mentioned and learn the difference between heap and stack allocation. `int i` doesn't increase memory pressure and is not counted as *GC Alloc* in Unity profiler, because it will most likely be allocated on the stack.

Answer (score 0):

Declaring `obj` gameObject outside the loop will be more performant as the variable no longer gets recreated on every iteration of the loop.

Also since Unity 5.5, the `foreach` GC alloc issue, has been resolved for common collections, so collections like `List<T>` no longer allocate, so there is no need to use `for`.

Another adjustment would be to change the following:

```
obj = otherObj.GetComponent<Transform>().gameObject;
```

To:

```
obj = otherObj.gameObject;
```

Both `gameObject` and `transform` are available as properties for any class deriving from `MonoBehaviour`.